# When VF page is refreshing the data on the page is loosing how to avoid it?

Tags: apex, visualforce, viewstate

I have a VF page where Account data is entered, before saving the record I am redirecting to a different page here I don't want to pass already entered values as parameters but I want to maintain view state (I shouldn't loose already entered data on Vf page).

Is it possible to do that ?

Here is my code :

**AccountPage :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="selectPrice">
       <apex:form>
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

        <apex:pageBlock
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveaccs}"
                    value="Save " />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                   <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name }" id="RID" required="true" />

                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Region__c}" />

                     <apex:inputField value="{!Account.State__c }" required="true" />

                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Price__c}" />

             </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!selectPrice}"  value="Select Price"> </apex:commandButton>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class selectPrice {

    public controllercls(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        // code
        accountRec = (Acount)controller.getRecord();

        //end

    }
    public PageReference selectPrice() {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/otherpage?Name='+accountRec.Name);
            return pr;

    }
}
```

**Otherpage:**

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!gobacktoAccPage}"  value="Go Back"> </apex:commandButton>
```

**Controller for Otherpage:**

```
public PageReference gobacktoAccPage() {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/AccountPage');// when I go to this page already entered values are showing as null
            return pr;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible in general and there are two crucial aspects in particular to achie the desired behaviour:

- the controller must be shared between the pages
- the page reference needs to be setRedirect(false)

See this example for more details

[How do I persistent data between VF pages (that change the view state) that share one controller?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101536/how-do-i-persistent-data-between-vf-pages-that-change-the-view-state-that-shar)